# xlpagertabstrip cannot hook up containerView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xlpagertabstrip

I feel like this is a really daft problem, but I cannot seem to hook my UIScrollView up to the containerView property. I have a UIViewController in the storyboard, whose class is MyCustomClass. MyCustomerClass inherits from ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController. However none of the outlets from ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController appear in the storyboard?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have done something like this

```
class exampleViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController {
    ...
}
```

[image: screenshot1]

Then in my case, I can see `containerView` in outlets:

[image: screenshot2]

And you can drag it to your scroll view.

Comment: @ioio007 for me containerView & buttonBarView is not showing in outlets, I have done like this only `exampleViewController: ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController`
Any idea or guidance please

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.

It seems to happen when the library is installed via Carthage.

I found an issue mentioned in the XLPagerTabStrip repository https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip/issues/244

Solution:

You can drag an own containerView by Storyboard，Naming Do not repeat XLPagerTabStrip of containerView，For example: xxxcontainerView，Then before super.viewDidLoad()，You can do this: self.containerView = self.xxxcontainerView
& same for the buttonBarView